# When I run 'flutter pub get' it gives me an error: Package not available (authorization failed)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I had this problem to add dependencies  my project, but I thought it was dependency problem
for example I couldn't add "video_player" or "showcaseview" dependency to my project6

tip : All these dependencies were already added to the project

Comment: Check the YAML formatting, maybe you did some mistakes. Try flutter clean and flutter pub get.

Comment: I Tried "Flutter clean" and "Flutter pub get".
This project was already working
But after a few days when I opened it, I got the error "run pub get" and when I run  "Flutter clean" and "Flutter pub get" I get the same error

Comment: Can't say anymore without chacking yaml

Comment: Shall I send you the contents of the yaml file?

Comment: Yeah, try to edit question and upload your yaml code/Screenshot if possible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and figured out that for me, the issue was running a VPN. It seemed to block the connection to where the packages are fetched from, so if you have a VPN ensure it's turned off, or the connection for flutter is split tunneled

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers

Comment: @NicoHaase it's not a duplicate as far as I can see. I'm saying my issue was that I had to turn my VPN off where as other ones are saying you need to turn a VPN on.

Answer (score 1):

Just run it with VPN and the problem would be fixed.

Comment: You might want to explain how that works and why it helps with the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, some countries such as Belarus, Myanmar, Iran, North Korea, Libya, and others are under US sanctions and American companies like Google (supporter of Dart language and Flutter framework) have blocked access to many of their services for citizens of these countries. Therefore, if someone uses a proxy from these countries or is present in these countries, they cannot use the services of American companies.